# SQL Server Update Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Here is my stored procedure for updating tables in SQL Server, but I can not seem to get it working what is wrong with the statement.

```
Update pc.PatientCopayId, pc.amount, pc.patientid, pc.apptid ,p.PaymentId,p.PaymentDate,p.PayorType,p.PaymentMethod,
      p.RefNumber,p.PaymentAmount,p.PayorId,pt.LastFirstName As PatientName,
      ISNULL((SELECT note FROM dbo.PatientNote WHERE NoteTypeId = 28 AND KeyValue = pc.PatientCopayId),'') AS Note
from [dbo].[PatientCopay] pc, dbo.pymt_Payment p, dbo.Patient pt
where ApptId =  @ApptId
  and p.PaymentId = pc.Paymentid
  And pt.PatientId = p.PayorId
```

Values and meaning

```
pc.amount, = @PaymentAmount
pc.patientid, = @PatientId
pc.apptid , = @ApptId
p.PaymentId, = @PaymentId
p.PaymentDate, = @PaymentDate
p.PayorType, = @PayorType
p.PaymentMethod, = @PaymentMethod
p.RefNumber, = @RefNumber
p.PaymentAmount, = @PaymentAmount
p.PayorId, = @PayorId
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `UPDATE` statement shoudl have the following form

`UPDATE TableName SET....`

Your update statement doesn't have the tablename or the SET keyword.

More Info [HERE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx)